# Email verification in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, registration

At this moment users can create an account at my website `(username, password, email)`

This wil create an entry in the database which stores the username, the hash of the password and the email adress and will set the level of the user to 0. After this it wil send an email with an url that contains the id of the user and a new hash of the hashed password.

```
$emailhash = password_hash($passwordHash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$url = "domain/validation.php?id=$id&hash=$emailHash";
```

At the validation page where the url points to, it wil use the hashed password as password and the hash from the email to check if the user is using an existing email adress.

```
password_verify(hashedPasswordFromDB, hashOfHashFromEmail);
```

Is this is a safe way to validate a user or should I add an extra table/column for an extra hash? And what are the pro's/cons of my current method and/or another method? (eg. simpler table...)

**EDIT**:
In case a user want to change his email adress ( something I'm adding at the moment ), I want to implement the same method (sending an url which contains the id, new email adress and a new hash of the hashed password + the new email adress). In my opinion this looks a bit devious but I don't see another way to change it.

Comment: This looks okay to me... This is how I do the "email verification".

Comment: Why would you involve the password?  If you are using PHP I would hope that you are using http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php.  Just create a separate sha1 hash using some random input and the email address itself and use that for the input to the hash.

Comment: I have a validation token column on the user, a random string which when the user clicks the link is matched to the user.

Comment: @PraveenKumar how do you handle email changes using that setup?

Comment: @Hedylogos Umm... Ha ha. No idea... `:(` So my solution or this one doesn't suit...

Comment: "a new hash of the hashed password + the new email adress" - How do you create it? Note that the user already knows the hash of his password, since you've sent it after the registration. He also knows the (faked) email address and his ID.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The user doesn't know what his hashed password is since there will be only send an hash of the hashed password.

Comment: @Hedylogos See my answer for a more flexible system. If you want to allow email address changing, that can easily be accommodated.  Of course you need separate handling code for each type of event.  For email changing, usually the way it works is that the user makes the request, you send them a new verification to their requested email, and you only change it when they have validated.  I added an "extra" column where you would store the new email, old email so you can act upon the request when the user validates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we've gotten into this, I'm going to throw in my 2 cents on not just doing this but doing it well.

Most people are suggesting that you add a column or 2 to the user table.  That is simple and it works.

But if you want to do this well there are things you want to consider:

- Will you also support password reset via email
- Will you age out the validation or reset
- Can you track someone attempting to compromise an account?
- Is there some sort of denial of service or other issue going on?

The best way to do this is to have a separate set of tables related to the user table that capture these type of account events.

Here's a list of typical account events:

- Account registration
- Account verification
- Account suspension
- Account deletion
- Password reset request
- Change email

In a robust system, each of these events, which all have a timestamp, will often have an expiration.

Many of them have an associated hash that needs to be stored and sent in an email.

They all have a "completed" flag to indicate if the implied action was completed.

So a better way of handling this is to have a separate related table to user.  For the sake of discussion this table would look something like this:

```
user_event
-----------
user_event_id (pk)
user_id (fk from user table)
created_on (timestamp)
event_type (registration | verification | password reset, etc)
expires_on (datetime) - manually set as is suitable
token (char40) - sha1
is_complete (tinyint)  A boolean to indicate if the action was completed
complete_on (timestamp)
user_ip (ip address of end user)
extra (varchar) : store the new email here.  Change to old email when you complete the request.
```

This is a far more robust way of persisting the data needed for these types of activities within a system, and also has some built in logging.  You have an audit trail of activities and can handle or prevent repeated requests.

You also can expire reset requests, and use those expired requests to do an aging activity like sending reminder emails to people who never completed their registration.

You now have a system that supports additional account related features without needing a separate additional table, and you can code new events by just creating a new event_type.  Those can just be a string, but you might also want to create a lookup table instead and use that as a foreign key to the user_event table.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, I'm already logging all account related events in for each event a different table with the timestamp, uid, ip, and what changed/happened. Your table looks much more extensive to the ones i'm currently using and I really like the possibility for an expiration date on a url. Was going to ask for the extra var, but since you've added it already is this perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Better create a separate token (some hash which is sent in the link as a query), which is stored with a timestamp in the DB. This way you have a link and can check with the timestamp, if the link has expired (compare the timestamp of the token with the current time of the request (when the user opens his link).

Comment: Also you can change the token if need, and free the token when the user is validated, without changing password. It's definitly better to have a specific column.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: extra hash or any random string in your database. There is no need for sending a password or even a hashed password over the line.